# How to check if current start and end dates are in previous period (start and end dates)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a tricky problem I am working on. I've made several attempts at capturing the data but have been unsuccessful.

I have a table in Power Bi that looks like this:

[image]

The key is in ascending order as well as the StartDate field. I would like to achieve the results in the "Period Overlap Delta" field but have had trouble trying to figure it out.

Basically, I'd like to assign a value of zero to any period (startdate-enddate combination) that is IN a previous period and take the date difference of those "super" periods.

Here is the DAX  to produce the table:

```
Cases = DATATABLE("Key", integer, "StartDate", datetime, "EndDate", datetime
        ,{
        {1, "01/01/2018", "01/10/2018"}
        , {2, "01/03/2018","01/03/2018"}
        , {3, "01/05/2018","01/07/2018"}
        , {4, "01/15/2018","01/16/2018"}
        , {5, "01/21/2018","01/24/2018"}
        , {6, "01/25/2018", "01/27/2018"}
        , {7, "01/25/2018","01/27/2018"}
        })
```

Thanks so much in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to know whether or not a certain row is overlapped by a previous row. By `previous` we mean the key is smaller than current row. By `overlapped` we mean the `StartDate` is earlier or equal to current row and `EndDate` is later or equal to current row, hence:

```
Overlapped = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        'Cases',
        'Cases'[StartDate] <= EARLIER('Cases'[StartDate]) &&
        'Cases'[EndDate] >= EARLIER('Cases'[EndDate]) &&
        'Cases'[Key] < EARLIER('Cases'[Key])
    )
)
```

[image: Overlapped]

And with this we just need to wrap it up and calculate the number of days with the `DATEDIFF` function:

```
Period Overlap Delta = 
VAR Overlapped =
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        'Cases',
        'Cases'[StartDate] <= EARLIER('Cases'[StartDate]) &&
        'Cases'[EndDate] >= EARLIER('Cases'[EndDate]) &&
        'Cases'[Key] < EARLIER('Cases'[Key])
    )
)
RETURN
IF(Overlapped, 0, DATEDIFF('Cases'[StartDate], 'Cases'[EndDate], DAY) + 1)
```

[image: Period Overlap Delta]

P.S. The use of `DATATABLE` to provide sample data is golden and should be promoted more often!

Comment: A tip of the hat to you my friend. Such an elegant solution and such a concise explanation, I am grateful for your response. Thanks!!

Comment: @StelioK Glad to help!